# Ceiling fan with 2 wall switches and missing remote

Tags: ceiling-fan

I am renting a house that has a Hampton Bay Clarington fan. I have the book. There is no remote here. One wall switch operates light and one operates fan.  The problem is that the fan is stuck on high and I cannot turn it down.  I bought a remote and have tried the 16 frequency combinations to avoid climbing.  After reading, someone said that I couldn’t use a remote with 2 switches operating.  Is there anyway to turn fan down without rewiring?

Comment: maybe the default isn't high, and maybe you can reset to defaults by killing power to the unit for a min or two, like from the breaker. Just a thought, no guarantees.

Comment: Is there pull chains on the fan?

Comment: All of the remote controllers that I know of are a separate module which is tucked under the fan bracket. You could take the shroud off and see what is there, but since this is a rental you are limited in what you should do to get something working right. Most fans that I know of have pull chains for speed control of the fan and for on/off of the light. The fan control is a sequence off-high-medium-low-off . . . or off-low-med-high-off . . . Do you see any pull chains?

Comment: If you turn the fan switch off and back on really fast, does the fan slow?

Comment: I think what may be motivating @Harper 's comment is that there are some systems for controlling fan/light combos separately with a single switch. I don't know how they work, but I gather that rapid cycling changes the single control from fan to light and vice versa. You say you have the instruction manual--what do the instructions say about this fan? You went out and bought a remote so presumably the manual references a wireless remote. If there is one, the receiver will be tucked under the shroud. Be careful on a ladder, if the fan would unexpectedly start spinning, then . . .

Comment: Thanks all.  I tried all of the above and I did climb the ladder and found the problem. There is no transmitter there!  I guess whoever installed it was not very smart or just didn’t care.  All 4 bedrooms have the double switch and the master is the only one with a fan.  It did not have pull chains and the book did have a remote.  Many comments online about that.  Not sure why fans couldn’t have both and you could just take off chains!  Solve problem with a box fan.  Cheap and reliable!